# How to test angular 1.5 component redirect without testing implementation?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-components

```
component = angular.element("<my-component></my-component>")

component.find("#redirectingButton).click();

expect(location).toBe(expectedLocation);
```

How do I test the above without testing implementation? Whatever test I write should not care if I am using href=, state.go, window.location, or whatever. I just want it to test that it takes me to the right place.

Note that I am trying to write integration tests here rather than unit tests.

Comment: The thing you're describing is e2e/functional test, and this should be tested with Protractor.

Comment: Except that I'm writing an integration test, not a unit test or an e2e/functional test.

Comment: You didn't mention that in the question. And *functional* refers more to the approach rather than the scope. ngMock cannot faithfully reproduce the behaviour of real app while keeping it from ruining things at the same time, and you will have hard time testing real router and DOM with Jasmine and ngMock.